# Shopify CLI error: cannot use gems with Shopify CLI, cannot load such file

Tags: rubygems, shopify, wdm

I'm starting to learn Shopify CLI via [this tutorial](https://shopify.dev/themes/getting-started/create), and am having some issues. I initially installed the CLI using Home-brew with `brew tap shopify/shopify` and `brew install shopify-cli`. Upon checking the Shopify version to ensure that it was installed correctly, I ran the command `shopify --version`, and received `@shopify/cli/3.40.1 darwin-x64 node-v19.6.0`. I was able clone the Dawn theme in my project folder with `shopify theme init`, and was able to select my Shopify store.

The issue lies with when I attempt to run the command `shopify theme dev`, where I am redirected to a login page, and get the below error upon a successful login:

```
[Note] You cannot use gems with Shopify CLI.
[LoadError] cannot load such file -- listen
       They are disabled.
       Please don't modify the CLI locally.
       If you would like to contribute to the CLI project, please refer to
       https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/blob/main/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md

✗ An unexpected error occured.
    To submit an issue include the stack trace.
    To print the stack trace, add the environment variable SHOPIFY_CLI_STACKTRACE=1.

[Note] You cannot use gems with Shopify CLI.
[LoadError] cannot load such file -- bugsnag
       They are disabled.
       Please don't modify the CLI locally.
       If you would like to contribute to the CLI project, please refer to
       https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/blob/main/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md
```

I've tried several ways to troubleshoot this from previous posts such as using `gem install wdm`, to which I get an error that states :

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.`

I've checked the gem version using `gem --version` , to which I get `3.0.3.1`. I have also confirmed that I am the store owner of the shopify store per the caution block on the documentation.

Though not recommended, I've also tried using the `sudo gem install wdm` command, but I still have the same error from the first code block when running theme dev. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You skipped a bunch of information. You should describe first off whether you met all the requirements of using the CLI. Second, you should describe how you installed the CLI. Finally, before you even dream of using it for business, describe how you validated that it installed correctly. Once you are at that point, it makes sense to describe using the CLI, and any problems from trying to use it. In other words, provide some details as your provided data is without any context.

Comment: Hello @DavidLazar, thanks for your feedback. I have edited the text above to provide more details. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: What is wdm? Why would want that gem?

Comment: @DavidLazar upon my research, wdm is a directory manager package that helps monitor directories for changes. It seems that on previous posts where others are having the same issue, using `gem install wdm` seemed to work for them.

Comment: That gem is 11 years old, for Windows. I cannot be 100% sure. But I am 99.9% sure that gem is not something anyone using Shopify CLI 3 in 2023 would ever have need to use. It is so old, and dead, as to be Ruby 1.9.2. We are now in world of Ruby 3.2 and Windows runs Linux. 

In fact, that is my advice to you if you run Windows. Use it for games. But use the Linux built-in to Windows to do work with Shopify. All your problems will probably just disappear if you do that.